# Blocked loading mixed active content laravel script nginx ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, haproxy, laravel

This is my virtual host configuration

```
    server {
        listen 877;
        listen [::]:877;
        root /wbs/carpool/www/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
#       return 301 https://juimonos.com$request_uri;
        location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

user connects to  example.com, gets automatically redirected to https://example.com .
certificate its present at haproxy level , provided by letsencrypt.

Connection flow is:
user---> haproxy --- ubuntu20 /nginx/virtualhost

When the website is accessed by https url, the list of users wont be displayed.

developer tools shows
"Blocked loading mixed active content “http:"

How to force nginx to traslate all websites to https or how to reconfigure laravel script to use https for everything?

locally i can view the list of users
[users shown locally , http method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLEBg.png)

from public https , users are not shown
[From https users not displayed, but excel exports the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrUE1.png)

same occurs with Apache.

please help me to get this fixed.

Comment: wait, you have haproxy and nginx and apache in one line involved? what is the server that now serves the content?

Comment: thanks for checking on this one.
the setup is simple
user connects to domain, domain connects to public ip on port 80 which is handled by haproxy which identifies for which domain the request is, in this case juimonos.com, then routes the traffic to internal server 192.168.1.4 nginx virtual host called juimonos.com which then replies to the request that came from internet but it doesnt work with haproxy , or https,  however website loads fine from internal ip and port hosted by nginx virtual host.

Comment: could you please update the question and reflect the same for apache? or is apache not involved at all?

Comment: as I update the question and see, that it has imho literally nothing to do with the configuration, I suggests that you contact the vendor of the application